# wordpress database table name update

Tags: mysql, wordpress, error-log

I am trying to read this error log so I can locate and update whatever is trying to find `wp_posts` and update it to `wp_oeai_posts` but cant for the life of me find any code looking for `wp_posts` in the db or the php

```
    WordPress database error Table 'testdb.wp_posts' doesn't exist for query SELECT u.* FROM uploads AS u LEFT JOIN approvals AS a ON a.uploadID = u.ID 
left join wp_posts as p on p.id = u.postid order by case when p.post_status = 'pending' then 0 else 1 end, submittedat desc made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), 
require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/twentyfourteen/page.php'),
get_template_part, locate_template, load_template,
require('/themes/twentyfourteen-child/content-page.php'), 
the_content, apply_filters('the_content'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, user_upload_manager_listsubmissions,
user_upload_manager_submissions->printsubmissions
```

Comment: `grep -r` is your friend. Or PhpStorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the code that needed to be updated, `listsubmissions.php`
`' left join wp_oeai_posts as p on p.id = u.postid'`